# JProfiler: will it have preventive analysis?

Tags: jprofiler

Is preventive analysis like this one [here](https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/inspections.jsp) something in JProfiler's roadmap?
Or is it available and I just miss it?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the "Inspections" view of the heap walker.